# video.js plugins not working

Tags: javascript, video.js

I'm trying to get any plugins from video.js to work, but I keep getting the errors as it pertains to `videojs('video_example_1)`, saying `videojs` is not defined. I copied the code from a recent plugin just to see if I'm doing something wrong. The exact error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: vjs is undefined
var video = videojs('video_example_1'); (line 41)
ReferenceError: videojs is not defined
```

Can someone help? Some code pasted below:

```
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://theonion.github.io/videojs-endcard/stylesheets/videojs.endcard.css"       
rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.4/video.js"></script>
<script src="http://theonion.github.io/videojs-endcard/javascripts/videojs.endcard.js">    
</script>

<video
id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"    
width="640" height="264"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>

<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />  
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />  

</video>
<script>
// Sync or Async, you decide.
function getRelatedContent(callback) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = "So Cool You'll HAVE to Click This!";
div.appendChild(p);
setTimeout(function(){
    // Needs an array
    callback([div]);
}, 0);
}

function getNextVid(callback) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.innerHTML = "Users will be taken to the VideoJS website after 10 seconds!"
anchor.href = "http://www.videojs.com/"
div.appendChild(anchor)
setTimeout(function(){
    callback(div);
}, 0);
}

var video = videojs('video_example_1');
video.endcard({
getRelatedContent: getRelatedContent,
//  getNextVid: getNextVid    //uncomment this for auto-playing video
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try executing your whole code after DOM has been successfully loaded, using `onload` handler on body:

```
[...]
<body onload="myOnLoadHandlerHere">...</body>
[...]
```

**JS script:**

```
function myOnLoadHandlerHere() {
    // Main logic here
}
```

It also seems that your video tag has **id="example_video_1"** but in your js code, you're trying to refer the id: **video_example_1**.

Answer (score -1):

In line here:

```
var video = videojs('video_example_1');
video.endcard({
getRelatedContent: getRelatedContent,
//  getNextVid: getNextVid    //uncomment this for auto-playing video
})
```

replace to:

```
var video = videojs('video_example_1');
video.endcard({
getRelatedContent: getRelatedContent
})
```